# r error - Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to query2.finance.yahoo.com:443

Tags: r, ssl, connection, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am connecting to the query2.finance.yahoo.com in order to scrape some information from the google finance for 3000 stocks (written in json as shown [here](https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=financialData)). I am able to retrieve information until, say 50 stocks or so, then it throws an error message saying:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to query2.finance.yahoo.com:443**
```

My guess is that the google team is block my server for suspicious activities for scraping information from their site, but I am not sure.

**Revised full error message:**

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to query2.finance.yahoo.com:443 
5.
fun(structure(list(message = msg, call = sys.call()), class = c(typeName, 
    "GenericCurlError", "error", "condition"))) 
4.
function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) 
{
    if (!is.character(type)) {
        i = match(type, CURLcodeValues) ... 
3.
curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) 
2.
getURL(json_url) 
1.
ScrapeYahooFinanceStats(ticker_char = new_tickers[1:length(new_tickers)])
```

Comment: I cannot find the specific reference, but they clearly state that they'll send a `403` when your rate limit is up.

Comment: Could post the link stating about the rate limit? Also, do you happen to know the alternative to bypass this error?

Comment: Other than "https://developer.yahoo.com/faq/", I cannot be more clear than *I cannot find the specific reference*, since I cannot find a numerical limit. However, my guess is that you cannot change it without (a) paying them, or (b) illegally breaking their system. "Bypass" is a big word, please be careful if you continue down that path.